# MethodNotAllowedHttpException Ajax Laravel 5.3 on route with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have simple operations like retrieve a country name from the database with ajax like:

```
$.ajaxSetup({headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'country',
    type: "post",
    async: asynchron,
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
...
```

And it works with pages with simple routes like:

```
Route::get('add_property', 'ViewController@add_property');
```

But the problem is that in pages with parametric URLs like:

```
Route::get('mod_property/{ref}', 'ViewController@mod_property')->name('mod_property');
```

It doesn't work, and in the preview of the response in the network debug window it shows up the **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** even if the paramètric route is not the one I'm calling from the ajax function, in fact it's this one:

```
Route::post('country', 'SimpleOperationsController@country');
```

So, how can I make ajax work in pages with parametric URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `url: 'country',` to `url: '\country',` to prevent relative paths.